# Save multiple model documents in one POST route with Mongoose/Express/Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a one-to-many relationship with my Search model and Result model. My user will do a search, select the results that were helpful, and hit a save button. That save button will hit an `app.post()` request. This should save an instance of the Search and one (or more) instance(s) of the selected Results. I can successfully save the Search instance with the following code:

**controllers/searchController.js**

```
const Search = require('../models/search');

exports.search_create_post = (req, res) => {
    let newSearch = new Search({ search_text: req.body.search_text });

    newSearch.save((err, savedSearch) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(savedSearch);
        }
    })
```

**routes/search.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const search_controller = require('../controllers/searchController');

//Search Routes
router.get('/', search_controller.search_home);

router.get('/results', search_controller.search_results_get);

router.post('/', search_controller.search_create_post);

module.exports = router;
```

How can I make it so that my user hitting the save button once will save the Search instance above and also the Results?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what I needed by passing two callbacks into my `post()` route and calling `next()` inside the first one along with passing the data the second one needed through the `req` object. My code is as follows:

**routes/search.js**

```
router.post('/', search_controller.search_create_post, result_controller.result_create_post);
```

**controllers/searchController.js**

```
exports.search_create_post = (req, res, next) => {
    let newSearch = new Search({ search_text: req.body.search_text });

    newSearch.save((err, savedSearch) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.searchData = savedSearch;
        }
          next();
    })
};
```

**controllers/resultController.js**

```
exports.result_create_post = (req, 
    let newResult = new Result({ url: 'req.body.url', search: req.searchData });

    newResult.save((err, savedResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(savedResult);
        }
    })
};
```